# Is Data from Star Trek able to swim?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Is Data from *Star Trek* able to swim?

Comment: Yes, but not in water. Troi taught him how to swim in moonlight.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to this conversation between Data and LaForge -- from the *TNG* episode, "[Descent, Part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Descent,_Part_II_(episode))" -- no, he can't.

> LAFORGE: **You know, Data, I've been thinking about some of the times we've had. Like that time we went sailing on Devala Lake. You remember that?**
>
> DATA: I have a complete memory record of that day.
>
> LAFORGE: **You decided to go swimming, and when you jumped out of the boat you sank straight to the bottom.**
>
> DATA: I did not have enough buoyancy to get back to the surface.
>
> LAFORGE: **You had to walk over a kilometre along the bottom to get back to shore.**
>
> DATA: One kilometre forty six metres.
>
> LAFORGE: It took almost two weeks to get the water out of your servos.
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: The Next Generation* - S07E01 - "Descent, Part II"</sub>

This was contradicted by a scene from *[Star Trek: Insurrection](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection)*, though, where it was shown that he had a built-in floatation device. Presumably, he can swim while utilising that feature, but likely not without doing so.

> DATA: In the event of a water landing, I have been designed to serve as a floatation device.
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: Insurrection* (1998)</sub>

Comment: Could be the floatation system was somehow added in between, although out of universe it’s obviously a joke.

Comment: I am pretty sure sometime in between Data got upgraded to a Class 3 yacht.

Comment: @Christian Sick Futurama reference bro!

Answer (score 6):

In the TNG Novel *[Metamorphosis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Metamorphosis_(novel))*, Data becomes (temporarily) human and does indeed learn how to swim, a requirement for all humanoid Starfleet officers.

> "You'll see," she said. "May I show you some strokes?"
> Data suddenly
> remembered Geordi, but his friend had made a strategic retreat and was
> now sitting on one of the lounges at the edge of the pool, talking to
> Riker. So Data accepted Pris's offer. She taught him only one stroke,
> something called a crawl even though it was one of the most efficient
> swimming strokes humans could use.
> After a great deal of splashing and
> sinking, he finally got his arms, legs, and head working together, and
> he and Pris swam side by side for a time.

Comment: Was Metamorphosis written by an 11 year old...? :-)

Comment: @Matt - It's not the best, either in terms of writing or plotting.